# swift downcast issue from superclass to subclass

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, swift3, xcode7

This is my code:

```
class Student {
    var name: String?
    init (name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class MasterStudent: Student {
    var degree: String?
    init(name: String, degree: String) {
        self.degree = degree
        super.init(name: name, degree: degree)
    }
}

fun updateStudent(stu: Student) {
    var count = 0
    for st in studentArray {            
        if (st.id == stu.id) {
            studentArray.removeAtIndex(count)
            st as! MasterStudent     //thread 1 signal :SIGABRT
            studentArray.append(stu)
        }
        count += 1
    }
}
```

If I pass the function `updateStudent` a `Student` object, the cast to `MasterStudent` results in a crash. I want to turn the `Student` object into a `MasterStudent` object.

thanks

Comment: Just cut that line. The line is meaningless (a cast all by itself does nothing), and you have no reason to cast in any case.

Comment: I think your misusing basic OOP programming. MasterStudent inherits from Student, so your **forced downcast** MAY result in crashes. Simply put you cannot ALWAYS downcast from Student to MasterStudent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would not compile as-is for me, so I made some small adjustments and updated it to Swift 3 in the IBM Swift Sandbox [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58366ed727a1b233cd0fa959).

I also added some example code demonstrating that the code does not fail when instantiating a `MasterStudent` object that is upcast to a `Student` and then downcast to a `MasterStudent`. However, instantiating a `Student` object will fail when it is downcast to a `MasterStudent`. It is not of the right type. Think of it this way, and I'm simplifying a bit -- a `Student` instance is missing the `degree` property that is required to match the behavior of a `MasterStudent`.

The `as!` operator should only be used when it is certain that the downcast will succeed. Here is one such example:

```
let obj:Any = "Hello World"
let obj2 = obj as! String
```

When using the `as!` operator, the compiler is trusting your judgment and will not provide a compile-time error. If the downcast is unsuccessful, your users will receive a run-time exception, which is generally to be avoided. The `as?` operator is a safer choice, as it will either downcast or return `nil` if unsuccessful.

Comment: first thanks for the fast answer, i saw what you wrote in your sandbox and when you using with the update function you send MasterStudent object not a Student object ,what i need is to send a Student and convert it to MasterStudent so im removing from the array the previous student and need to add a MasterStudent with all the additional fields thanks again

Comment: i understood from your privious comment that a Student cannot convert to MasterStudent, what can i do to update a Student to MasterStudent even the field degree is lack

Comment: I created another Sandbox snapshot [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5836feca27a1b233cd0fa980) that creates a new MasterStudent object instead of downcasting. Note that the MasterStudent initializer now has a default degree value of "Masters" if the `degree` parameter is not passed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can only downcast `st` to `MasterStudent` if it the `st` object is already an instance of `MasterStudent`. Otherwise you would need to create a new `MasterStudent` object:

```
MasterStudent(name: st.name, degree: "...")
```